# Callback function of a button in NUXT is not firing

Tags: jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

The button is simple html buttton. The callback function oncallback is not firing. Same working when trying to work on a html page. But not working on NUXT Vue application.

The button click event is firing by an external js file.

I am trying to catch the response of the payment as per the documentation in the below link.

http://forte.net/devdocs/a_checkout/co_product_overview_v2.htm#Coding

```
 <button
   id="btnPay"
   type="button"
   callback="oncallback"
   billing_street_line2_attr="hide"
   billing_company_name_attr="hide"
   billing_attr="hide"
   version_number="1.0"
   method="sale"
   button_text="Make Payment"
 >Pay Now</button>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    oncallback(e) {
      console.log("captured callback");
      alert(e.data);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding a click event on the button that will trigger your oncallback method

Comment: @martcube click event was there in the external js file (external domain) which was loaded in the page.

Comment: try posting your question directly to Nuxt on their github, you will have response from them